# Fine Uploader concurrency issues

Tags: backbone.js, concurrency, fine-uploader

I'm using Fine Uploader to upload files directly to Amazon S3 (not relevant to the issue).

What I'm doing is to generate an "attachment" backbone.js model (which generates an unique ID), and passing that ID to the uploader via `setParams` in the `submit` event, in order for me to identify the attachment in the `complete` event and take appropriate actions.

The problem is manifesting when uploading multiple files at the same time (tried with 10 files). Fine Uploader apparently calls the `submit` callback too fast, and I am getting duplicate model IDs in the `complete` event.

If I add breakpoints to the `submit` event and do nothing, just hit "play" again, the concurrency problem is no longer present.

Part of my code is:

```
var self = this;
this.uploader.on('submit', function() {
    var attachment = new Market.InboxPage.Models.Attachment(); // generates a new model with a unique ID
    self.attachments[attachment.cid] = attachment; // self.attachments is a model collection

    self.uploader.setParams({'cid': attachment.cid});
});

this.uploader.on('complete', function(event, id, file, response) {
    self.attachments[response.metadata.cid].set({ // getting duplicate data here
        filename: response.metadata.qqfilename,
        key: response.metadata.key,
        filesize: response.metadata.filesize
    });
    self.attachments[response.metadata.cid].updateInDom();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your calls to `setParams`.  You are effectively overwriting the params for all existing files with each call to `setParams`.  Instead, you should be targeting a specific file with each call to `setParams`.  `setParams` allows you to do this by specifying a file ID as a parameter to the `setParams` call.  For example:

```
this.uploader.on('submitted', function(event, id, name) {
    var attachment = new Market.InboxPage.Models.Attachment(); // generates a new model with a unique ID
    self.attachments[attachment.cid] = attachment; // self.attachments is a model collection

    self.uploader.setParams({'cid': attachment.cid}, id); });
```

Notice how I switched your logic to the `submitted` event, which is called after the file has been successfully submitted, and an ID is available.

Comment: That worked, so, awesome! One more small thing. There are 2 ways of doing `setParams`. Can you confirm that the following is syntactically correct? (it seems to work) `jQuery('#something').fineUploaderS3('setParams', {'cid': attachment.cid}, id);`

Comment: Yes, you can call `setParams` that way as well, if you wish.